# MySQL Generated Columns of date type

Tags: mysql

i use mysql version 5.7

i have a field devicetime which is a `datetime` field.

for some reason i want to add a generated column which stores only the `date` part of the devicetime field.

i have tried the following statement

```
alter table mytable
add COLUMN recorddate date generated always as date(devicetime) stored;
```

i get an error

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  'date(devicetime) stored' at line 2
```

i have taken the inputs from MySQL documentation from [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html).

my current table structure is like this

[image]

Comment: not interested in triggers btw.

Comment: What is your current table structure ?

Comment: You may only use linear and deterministic functions in computed columns.  I think the issue with `date` (and probably the other date/time functions) is that two independent users might not get the same result consistently, because of timezone issues.

Comment: One workaround might be to store the datetime as a plain string, and then create a computed column which is a date substring of that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that makes sense, except that "deviceTime" is a DATETIME field (not TIMESTAMP) which does not convert to the session timezone (it stores literally what you give it).

Comment: @Vatev Yes...my comment did not make complete sense, but I'll bet the reason is something along these lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For whatever reason MySQL needs some `()`'s around the expression:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable ` 
ADD COLUMN  `recorddate` DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (date(devicetime)) STORED;
```

Comment: somehow the answer turned out to be a syntactical issue only.... adding parenthesis has solved my issue...

Answer (score 0):

One solution came into my mind is,you can store **`TIMESTAMP`** into table.
And when try to get anywhere in your SYSTEM you can use [**`DATE_FORMAT()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)  and [**`STR_TO_DATE()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) function to whatever part you required from that actual data.